# TYPO3 9.5.11: No class named EXT: ap_docchecklogin (but class exists)

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I use the extension "ap_docchecklogin" (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ap_docchecklogin/), which works under Typo3 8.7.29. Only under a fresh TYPO3 version 9.5.11 I get the following message:

> No class named EXT:ap_docchecklogin/Classes/DocCheckAuthenticationService.php:&Antwerpes\ApDocchecklogin\DocCheckAuthenticationService

This is the code where the error happends:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['initFEuser'][] = 'EXT:ap_docchecklogin/Classes/DocCheckAuthenticationService.php:&Antwerpes\ApDocchecklogin\DocCheckAuthenticationService->bypassLoginForCrawling';
```

Of course, I cleared the cache and renewed PHP Autoload. I also looked at the extension and the class definitely exists.

Both Typo3 versions run on the same server under the same settings.

Where is the difference between the Typo3 versions? Why it works in version 8? Has anyone ever had similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the changelog here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Deprecation-86279-VariousHooksAndPSR-15Middlewares.html, Hooks which is used in the extension has deprecated in the TYPO3 9 LTS version.

You can see the issue here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87357

you can use a custom PSR-15 middleware instead.

I made small changes in the code and it's no longer showing an error. Don't know this works for you or not (Functionality I am talking about)

But try this way...

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']
    ['SC_OPTIONS']
    ['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']
    ['initFEuser'][] = 'Antwerpes\\ApDocchecklogin\\DocCheckAuthenticationService->bypassLoginForCrawling';
```

Does this help?

Comment: Many thanks, extension now works without errors and I will check the functionality.